# iOS 10 and Xcode 8 Today Extension not working on device

Tags: ios, xcode, ios10, xcode8, today-extension

I have an app with a Today Extension and I now updated from Xcode 8 beta 6 to Xcode 8 GM.

In Simulator everything runs fine but the Today Extension is not working on the device.

The Extension stops working, when I add a subview, but there is no crash or something just this line in the output window:

> Program ended with exit code: 0

Thats all :(

Any idea, what I can do or how I can debug this?

Thanks,
Stefan

Comment: Any news on this? I'm having a similar issue.

Comment: I'm having this similar issue. :(